# Homebrew - I cannot install from source. Command clang requires CLT

Tags: xcode, homebrew, big-sur

I have installed XCode 12 from my MBP. Then I cleaned old Command Line Tools. After that I downloaded CLT 12 from Apple website and installed it fine.

Now The issue is I cannot build anything from source with brew. It keeps throwing at me the dialog below. I have tried

`sudo xcode-select -r` - No success
`sudo xcode-select --install` I get error message (rightfully so) `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

I have tried anything I could but I still get the same dialog.

The commands:
`sudo xcode-select -p`shows `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`
`which clang` shows `/usr/bin/clang`

and `brew config`

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.5.2
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: cd4a3c0588abb82d916bc8558f4c157e951d449d
Last commit: 3 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 63a79e6180f8015f815cd99f148a2cc9c923032f
Core tap last commit: 26 minutes ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit haswell
Clang: 12.0 build 1200
Git: 2.24.3 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 14.0.1
macOS: 11.0-x86_64
CLT: 12.0.0.0.1.1599194153
Xcode: 12.0
```

Sample Command for testing the issue is `brew install wxmac --HEAD` and the dialog I get is this

[image]

I have run out of ideas and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

I had kept my Copy of Xcode 12 Beta 5 and did extract and dragged to Applications folder. Then I ran `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer` and all is well.

Seems like Xcode 12 GM is not working well with macOS 11.0 Beta 7

Comment: Interesting and great workaround.  Does `brew doctor` show different results on switching default tool sets here?

Comment: Thanks for compliment :) but I don't get the question

Comment: I wondered if the doctor tool would tell you and us what was wrong with the setup or tools. I can’t reproduce your errors.

Comment: May be because they don't officially support it yet!